# How to select tag by content of tag before it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I have html page that looks like that:

```
<div>
<h1>First Item</h1>
<p> the text I want </p>
</div>

<div>
<h1>Second Item</h1>
<p> the text I don't want </p>
</div>
```

The heading of "First Item" may be located at different tag levels in each page scrape so the index is not fixed.

I want some selection that looks like (that's a pseudo-code).

```
from lxml import html

locate_position = locate(html.xpath(//div/h1[contains("First Item")])))

scrape = html.xpath(//div[locate_position]/p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to match the preceding sibling:

```
/p/preceding-sibling::contains(h1,"First Item")
```

An option closer to your example would be:

```
/div[contains(h1, "First Item")]/p
```

Which gets p's that are the children of div's that have an h1 child.

Comment: Your examples aren't valid (contains needs two args). I think you'd want `//div[contains(h1,'First Item')]/p`.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with bs4 4.7.1 if you are prepared to consider using it. You can use the `:contains pseudo class` to specify the `h1` must contain the search string and the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to specify that match must have a `p` tag immediately after.

> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and
>   matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first
>   element, and both are children of the same parent element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div>
<h1>First Item</h1>
<p> the text I want </p>
</div>

<div>
<h1>Second Item</h1>
<p> the text I don't want </p>
</div>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

#multiple matches possible
matches = [match.text for match in soup.select('h1:contains("First Item") + p')]
print(matches)

# first match (useful if only one match expected or first required)
soup.select_one('h1:contains("First Item") + p').text
```

Comment: however beautifulsoap is faster to get the final text, I feel it more difficult to select tags in non- xpath approch!

Comment: Hi, right click on element copy selector (for verbose selectors). It only takes a little practice to be familiar enough with html to write your own more concise. You can easily practice here https://flukeout.github.io/  and read up here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors . For web-scraping I think it useful to be comfortable with both.